# Karate scenario cannot be executed from intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, karate

Unable to execute karate scenario from intellij 
OS: Mac
Intellij version: Karate scenario cannot be executed from intellij
Karate version:

> ```
> compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '4.7.0'
>
> testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
> testCompile group: 'com.intuit.karate', name: 'karate-apache', version: '0.9.3'
> testCompile group: 'com.intuit.karate', name: 'karate-junit4', version: '0.9.3'
> ```

Error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix Cucumber and Karate which is not supported. Refer to [this issue for the gory details](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/444#issuecomment-419852761).

So try without the Cucumber dependency. For instructions on how to get started on IntelliJ - please refer this video: https://youtu.be/W-af7Cd8cMc

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, As mentioned in the video I added "Cucumber for java" which has dependency on "Gherkin" . But still unable to run a single feature file or single secnario.
I am able to run the test from the junit runner defined as below from intellij.

Comment: @BharathanKumaran time for you to follow this process then: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - make sure you provide clear step by step instructions on how to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved by setting the Switch IDE Boot JDK to default and deleting the cache and restart.
The cause this was due to multiple jdk I have installed in my machine (JDK8 and JDK 12).
Deleted the old one and set the boot JDK to 12.

The issue is not with Karate library, its with the IntelliJ configuration.

Answer (score -3):

I solved this by loading karate framework in eclipse 8 and then using intelij